# group by on time intervals in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

I have a query that is returning the time for each records, and time format is like

> "060000"

I want to group by the records  in three groups:

```
first group whose time is <=072000 (Right Time)
second group whose time is >072000 and <=074500  (Late Comers)
Third group whose time is >074500       (For Half Day)
```

Comment: Can you show sample input and more important sample output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement and a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.TimeGroup, COUNT(t1.*)
FROM (SELECT [...],
      CASE 
         WHEN Time <= 072000 THEN 'Right Time'
         WHEN Time BETWEEN 072001 AND 074500 THEN 'Late Comers'
         WHEN Time > 074500 THEN 'For Half Day'
      END AS "TimeGroup"
   FROM [...]) t1
GROUP BY t1.TimeGroup
```